# Star rating appears completely wrong

Tags: html, css

I have a star-based rating. Until now I was running it on Node Js and it was working fine and looking correctly. Now I'm running my localhost on Apache server, and the star rating looks funny don't even know why. Output:

[image]

.

How it should look:

[image]

Html:

```html
<div class="star-ratings">
   <div class="star-ratings-top" id="star-ratings-top1"><span>★</span><span>★</span><span>★</span><span>★</span><span>★</span></div>
   <div class="star-ratings-bottom"><span>☆</span><span>☆</span><span>☆</span><span>☆</span><span>☆</span></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.star-wrapping{
    margin-top:20px;
    padding-left: 30px;
  }
  .star-ratings {
    float:left;
    display:block;
    unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
    color: #ECECEB;
    font-size: 40px;
    position: relative;
    margin-left:10px;
    height:40px;

  }
  .star-ratings .star-ratings-top {
    color: gold;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0.5;
    display: block;
    left: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .star-ratings .star-ratings-bottom {
    z-index: 0;
  }
```

Comment: You're serving/interpreting your file with the wrong encoding.

Comment: @deceze How do I know in which encoding to do it?

Comment: @deceze Yes, just needed to add <meta charset="UTF-8">. Thanks!